# Turn off || operator optimization

Tags: c++, short-circuiting

Is there any option in VS C++ 2017 so that when it builds the following program both `f()` and `g()` are called?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool f()
{
    cout << "f" "\n";
    return true;
}
bool g()
{
    cout << "g" "\n";
    return false;
}
int main()
{

    if (f() || g())
        cout << "hello";
    cin.ignore(1);
}
```

Comment: You cannot "turn off" something that is part of the core language.

Comment: That's not optimization, that's short-circuiting.

Comment: @Swordfish in some cases you can ... not this one.

Comment: @M.M huh? example?

Comment: Some compilers have switches to turn off exceptions, or type compatibility requirements,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not, this behavior (short-circuiting) is fundamentally part of logical operators.

What you can do instead is use the bitwise or operator `|`. But make sure to add a comment stating that this is not a mistake but on purpose!

In any case, if your function calls are not as simple as `f()` you should consider instead introducing a separate variable (or variables) to make it more obvious what your code is doing (calling two functions unconditionally, then using both their return values).

Comment: Comments can get out of sync with code (e.g. if something changes, programmers are notorious for not updating comments to match the intent of the code).   As a rough rule, relying on comments to explain that code is not mistaken, even if it looks like a mistake, is a good reason not to use that code.    Introducing "a separate variable (or variables)" is actually a more correct and less error-prone solution to the problem.

Answer (score 10):

Short circuit evaluation is part of the language specification. You can't just turn it off.
You could instead assign `f()` and `g()` calls to variables and then evaluate those:

```
bool f_ret = f();
bool g_ret = g();
if (f_ret || g_ret)
    cout << "hello";
```

Comment: Instead of introducing variables to the scope you could use `if (auto f_  = f(), g_ = g(); f_ || g_)`

Answer (score 2):

If you have at least one of your functions return a UDT with an `operator||` defined:

```
#include <iostream>

struct my_bool
{
    bool value;
    my_bool(bool value) : value{ value } {}
    operator bool() const { return value; };
    my_bool operator||(my_bool rhs) const { return value || rhs.value; }
};

my_bool f()
{
    std::cout << "f()\n";
    return true;
}

my_bool g()
{
    std::cout << "g()\n";
    return false;
}

int main()
{

    if (f() || g())
        std::cout << "hello\n";
}
```

both sides will be evaluated.

But. You. Don't. Want. To. Do. That.<sup>*)</sup>

<sup>*) unless the goal is to write obfuscated code ;)</sup>

Comment: Your `operator||()` would be more applicable if it accepted an argument of type `my_bool` and returns `my_bool`.    As is,  `f() || x() || y()` where `x()` and `y()` each return `bool` would not call `y()`, which is not quite what is expected of the solution.

Comment: @Peter. Right. Changed.

Answer (score 2):

The probably simplest solution is writing:

```
if (f()+g())
    cout << "hello";
```

Output:

```
f
g
hello
```

Operator `+` does not have any "short circuit evaluation". Logically, expression `f() + g()` is equivalent to `f() || g()` for the following reason: Operands of operator `+` are converted to integral values, where a `false` gives `0`, and a `true` gives `1`. The result of `f() + g()` is then in the range between `0..2`.  As this integral result is used where a boolean value is expected, it is converted back to boolean, whereby `0` is treated as `false` and everything `>0` is treated as `true`.

Comment: Might get a bit of a shock with this solution if any functions being added return something other than `bool`.   Consider what happens if `g()` is changed for some reason to return `int`, and to return values of `0`, `1`, or `-1` under specified conditions.   For all cases where it returns `-1`,  `f() + g()` will return give a result of `0`, even if `f()` returns `true`.